# How to change the WooCommerce checkout texts?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the text "Billing details" and "Your order".

I don't have access to the Wordpress database, but I do have access to all the internal files of the theme and WP.

As I'm only going to sell in 1 language, I don't need a dynamic text.

Would it be possible to change anything in WP's PHP files?

Here is an image of the page https://wpxpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/woocommerce-checkout-page-simplified-css.png

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

You can use Loco Translate Plugin. It is free.
Just install it and translate your text from "Billing details" and "Your order" to what ever you want.

**Method 2:**

Also you can do that by css:

```
h3.step-title span {
  display: none;
}
h3.step-title span:after {
  content: 'whatever it is you want to add';
}
```

tested and worked.